# MonoDevelop debugger is on strike as of this morning

Tags: iphone, debugging, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, ios-simulator

with MonoTouch 5, MonoDevelop 2.8:

1. Create new single view iPhone application.
2. Add a breakpoint to the application entry point
3. Click Debug (to iOS Simulator)

MonoDevelop should stop at the breakpoint, but it doesn't. Instead, "Socket error while
connecting to 127.0.0.1 on port 10001: Connection refused" is output to the
Application Output window.

This all worked yesterday :(

I filed a bug on Xamarin's bugzilla

Comment: MonoDevelop 2.6 connects fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to have vanished. So, no idea what it was, or what fixed it.

The bug report I filed is here, in case anyone wants to join in the fun: http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1544

Answer (score 1):

First make sure you're using **iPhone Simulator|Debug** (and not **iPhone Simulator|Release**). It's an easy mistake (I did it again yesterday) and will show this *exact* same error.

Next look if something else might be using the same **10001** port. To see if this is the case one a terminal window and try this command:

```
 sudo lsof -i -P | grep -i "listen"
```

That will show you every port listening on from your OSX machine. If something uses **10001** then it will need to be shutdown to allow.

Comment: helpful suggestions for the next guy!